# JavaScript-produced elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a game so I stared at it for awhile (and yes, I did look at the developer log console for errors), and found no errors (within my reasoning) of why it wouldn't open a battle function.

It is saying that for whatever reason that Giant is not defined when clicked, Zombie is not defined when clicked, and for Giant Spider it says something along the lines of missing parameter. I am quite sure it falls down to the code below -->

```
for(var z = 0; z < monsters.length; z++) {
  Gid("atkOpt_container").innerHTML += ("<div onclick='battle(" + monsters[z].name + "," + this.value + ")' class='monsterContainer' value=" + z + "><div class='monsterT'>" + monsters[z].name + "</div><table><tr><td>Strength</td><td>Health</td><td>XP</td><td>Level</td></tr><tr><td>" + monsters[z].dmg + "</td><td>" + monsters[z].hp + "</td><td>" + monsters[z].xp + "</td><td>" + monsters[z].lvl + "</td></tr></table></div>");
}
```

If you wish to look at all the code look below. And if you're wondering why everything is so small it's because I'm making it on my phone, and transferred it to ask via GitHub.

```js
var monsters = []; //All monsters are stored here
//All types of monsters are listed below
monsters.push(new monster_prototype("Giant", 50, 30, 1, 20, 20));
monsters.push(new monster_prototype("Giant spider", 20, 50, 1, 15, 30));
monsters.push(new monster_prototype("Zombie", 50, 50, 2, 40, 70));

for (var z = 0; z < monsters.length; z++) {
  Gid("atkOpt_container").innerHTML += ("<div onclick='battle(" + monsters[z].name + "," + this.value + ")' class='monsterContainer' value=" + z + "><div class='monsterT'>" + monsters[z].name + "</div><table><tr><td>Strength</td><td>Health</td><td>XP</td><td>Level</td></tr><tr><td>" + monsters[z].dmg + "</td><td>" + monsters[z].hp + "</td><td>" + monsters[z].xp + "</td><td>" + monsters[z].lvl + "</td></tr></table></div>");
} //Where I believe the error occurs, it basically loads all monster stats into a div

function Gid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  } //So I don't have to write the whole document.getElementById

function monster_prototype(name, hp, dmg, lvl, xp, money) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.dmg = dmg;
    this.lvl = lvl;
    this.xp = xp,
      this.money = money;
  } //How I store the monsters info

function save() {
  localStorage.player = JSON.stringify(playerStats);
}

var playerStats = {
  lvl: 1,
  xp: 0,
  xpToLvl: 100,
  name: null,
  dmg: null,
  hp: null,
  money: 100
};

if (localStorage.player === undefined) {
  save();
  playerSetup();
} else {
  playerStats = JSON.parse(localStorage.player);
  alert("Welcome back " + playerStats.name);
  refreshStats();
} //Checks if the player is new, and if so starts the main player setup. If not it loads it

function refreshStats() {
    Gid("maxDmg").innerHTML = "Max damage: " + playerStats.dmg;
    Gid("hp").innerHTML = "Health: " + playerStats.hp;
  } //Refreshes some stats

function playerSetup() {
  document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.display = "none";
  $("#class_container").show();
}

function classChosen(pClass) {
    if (pClass === "Juggernaut") {
      playerStats.hp = 100;
      playerStats.dmg = 10;
    } else if (pClass === "Average Joe") {
      playerStats.hp = 60;
      playerStats.dmg = 30;
    } else {
      playerStats.hp = 40;
      playerStats.dmg = 70;
    }
    refreshStats();
    document.getElementById("class_container").style.display = "none";
    var getName = prompt("What is your name?");
    playerStats.name = getName;
    document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.display = "block";
    save();
  } //Starts the class choosing feature

function toggle(id) {
    $("#" + id).toggle();
  } //Toggles display (Hidden or block)

function restartGame() {
  localStorage.removeItem('player');
  location.reload();
}

function battle(enemy, enemyLoc) {
    console.log(enemy + " and " + enemyLoc);
    enemy = enemy.toLowerCase();

    Gid("attackInfo").innerHTML = "";
    var battleWords = ['slashed', 'bashed', 'stabbed', 'punched'];

    var enemyHp = monsters[enemyLoc].hp;
    var enemyDmg = monsters[enemyLoc].dmg;
    var playerHp = playerStats.hp;
    var playerDmg = playerStats.dmg;

    var battleLoop = setInterval(function() {
      var atkName1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * battleWords.length);
      var atkName2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * battleWords.length);
      var enemyDealt = Math.round(Math.random() * enemyDmg);
      var playerDealt = Math.round(Math.random() * enemyDmg);

      playerHp -= enemyDealt;
      enemyHp -= playerDealt;

      Gid("attackInfo").innerHTML += ("<strong>•</strong>" + enemy + " " + battleWords[atkName1] + " you and dealt " + enemyDealt + " damage to you and you now have " + playerHp + " health remaining.<br>You " + battleWords[atkName2] + " the " + enemy + " and dealt " + playerDealt + " damage. The " + enemy + " has " + enemyHp + " health remaining.<br><br>");

      if (enemyHp <= 0 && playerHp <= 0) {
        clearInterval(battleLoop);
        alert("You both died at the same time! A win... but mainly a loss. Game over");
        restartGame();
      } else if (enemyHp <= 0) {
        clearInterval(battleLoop);
        alert("You won!");
        playerStats.money += monsters[enemyLoc].money;
        playerStats.xp += monsters[enemyLoc].xp;

        if (playerStats.xp >= playerStats.xpToLvl) levelUp();
      } else if (playerHp <= 0) {
        alert("Game over");
        clearInterval(battleLoop);
        restartGame();
      }
    }, 1000);
  } //Main battle, this is the function that won't load

function levelUp() {

  } //TBA
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
}
#atkOpt_container {
  display: none;
}
#attackBtn {
  background-color: black;
  width: 96px;
  color: yellow;
  border: 4px groove red;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#attackInfo {
  float: left;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 250px;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#class_container {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px groove black;
}
.playerClass {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px groove red;
  color: #00FF00;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}
#title {
  width: 95%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #00FF00;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
#atkOpt_container {
  z-index: 11;
  width: 275px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.monsterContainer {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 5px groove red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.monsterT {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  background-color: Cyan;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="class_container">
    <div id="title">Choose a class</div>
    <div onclick="classChosen(this.innerHTML)" class="playerClass">Juggernaut</div>
    <div onclick="classChosen(this.innerHTML)" class="playerClass">Masculine Mat</div>
    <div onclick="classChosen(this.innerHTML)" class="playerClass">Average Joe</div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="attackBtn" onclick="toggle('atkOpt_container'); toggle('mainContainer');">Attack</div>
      <div id="attackInfo"></div>
      <div id="maxDmg">Max damage: 0</div>
      <div id="hp">Health: 0</div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="restartGame();">Delete stats</button>
  </div>
  <div id="atkOpt_container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should post your code here not like to another site.

Comment: You should post *properly formatted* code here.

Comment: First thing you should do is look at the developer tools of your browser and see what errors are showing up. I see several when I click on Attack in the snippet. Also, please explain what you expect it to do that it is not doing. See [ask] for information on what makes a good question, especially the part about [mcve]...

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I did, I looked around it as many ways as I could. I said it would not open the battle function. And I don't know why and it is saying that for whatever reason that Giant is not defined when clicked, Zombie is not defined when clickded, and for Giant Spider it says something along the lines of missing parameter. I've tried experimenting and have had no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
"<div onclick='battle(" + monsters[z].name + "," + this.value + ")'
```

produces

```
<div onclick='battle(whatever, whatever)'
```

Which is wrong, because you do not have quotes around the strings. You need to quote them. So add in the `"`

```
"<div onclick='battle(\"" + monsters[z].name + "\",\"" + this.value + "\")'
```

Ideally you would use DOM methods such as `createElement` and `addEventListener` so you would not have to deal with this.